# Remove spacing before contents, figure list, table list and glossary titles without changing font

Tags: fonts, spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

The relevant parts of my code are as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  {\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\large\bfseries\sffamily}%
{\thesubsection}{5mm}{}
  
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[block]
  {\sffamily\bfseries}
  {\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}


% abbreviations package
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textsf{#1}} %Change acronym name font   

% \makenomenclature
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot]{glossaries}
\newacronym{eg}{e.g.}{example abbreviation}
\makeglossaries

\usepackage[a4paper, 
            left=30mm, right=30mm,
            top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}


\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \LARGE \bfseries \sffamily
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \thechapter.\nobreakspace
    \fi
    #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 20\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\sffamily


\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Contents}

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations,nonumberlist]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}


\include{Introduction/Introduction}
\include{main/main}

\emergencystretch=1em
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I want all fonts to be \sffamily which they currently are.
I also want the space above main headings such as contents and table list to be smaller (matching what I've set for the chapters (10pt +margin)).

I tried

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc}{\vspace{-1cm}\@starttoc}{}{}
```

But that didn't work on my abbreviations and only moved content rather than the titles (that is, it reduced the space after the titles and I want to reduce the space *before*)

I also tried adding

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\huge\bfseries\sffamily}{\thechapter.}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{10pt}{-1.5em}{1.1\parskip}
\titlelabel{\thetitle\quad}
```

Which is prefect for the spacing but has changes some of the font back to default (for example in the contents page not the chapter headings but all the subheadings).

Is there a way to get the spacing I want and keep my fonts?
Thank you

Comment: Please make your example self contained.

Comment: @daleif What do you mean by self contained? Do you mean that I need to include the text in the Introduction.tex and main.tex files?

Comment: As your example is now there are files we do not have access to. You should be able to replace the `\include`'s by something more relevant.

Comment: Note that your example has no chance of even compiling as `\printbibliography` is undefined as your example does not load `biblatex`. And `\glsnamefont` is undefined at the time you're trying to change it. It might be an idea to start over with this example instead.

Comment: It should be mentioned that you can achieve the same results as titlesec or tocloft by directly modifying \@makechapterhead etc.  The source code in book.cls is simple by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

In book class a lot changed when I used
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}% instead of \usepackage{etoolbox}.
I then inserted

```
\renewcommand{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-0.25in} % Title is 1in from top
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{1.0\baselineskip}% 1 double space after title
```

and the same for the 'lot' (instead of 'toc').

In the title formats I repeated the desired font:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Large\bf}{\thechapter{.~}}{0pt}{\Large\bf\lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen}%
```

Maybe this helps in report class as well.

Answer (score 0):

The ToC etc., titles are set with a `\chapter*` command. You have redefined your code for `\chapter` so you also need to redefine `\chapter*` code.

After this you can use `tocloft` commands like

```
\addtolength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-30pt}
```

to move the ToC title upwards.